# sonarqube 4 server migration

Tags: postgresql, sonarqube, database-migration, server-migration

I'm trying to move a sonarqube 4.4 installation from one machine to another. What's more we would also like to change the database server from Oracle to Postgres 9.3.

What my plan was initially is that I would shutdown the sonar server, the database adminstrator would dump existing database, migrate it to postgres in the new server and I would zip the existing server installation and move it along to the new server. Then I would start the server.

However I've run into problems, even though sonarqube 4.4 booted fine, when I hit 
`http://new-server:9001/sonar4`
I was getting a 404 response from sonar.

At some point I tried unzipping the server file anew in which case I managed to see the projects and the dashboards but no analysis data existed, even though last analysis time was available.

Any ideas or clues what am I missing?

Also, the driver in sonarqube for postgres is 9.1.xxx can I update this or should we use postgres 9.1 to make sure the driver is compatible with the database?

Answer (score 0):

How is your ..\conf\sonar.properties? Normally, you should have changed:

## sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost/XE

Did you use some tool to migrate Oracle to Postgress? I thought it was not possible.

Do not hesitate to ask for further precision.
Regards.